# Accessing union elements in C++

Tags: c++, struct, unions

I have been implementing a communication protocol in C++ and I have decided to model one packet in below given manner.

```
union control_pkt_u{
    struct pkt_parts_t{
        uint8_t header[3];                                // Control packet header
        uint8_t payload[NO_PYLD_BYTES_IN_CONTROL_PACKET]; // Control packet payload
    };
    uint8_t pkt_array[NO_BYTES_IN_PACKET];
};
```

As soon as I need to access to the elements of the union

```
pkt.pkt_parts_t.header[0] = APP_MSG_DEB;
```

I receive an error during compilation:

```
invalid use of struct Manager::control_pkt_u::pkt_parts_t
```

Please can anybody tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: `pkt_parts_t` is not a data member, it is a member type. You need to instantiate it.

Comment: your `control_pkt_u` has only one member which is an array of `uint8_t`s. What is the type of `pkt` anyhow? Please read about [mcve]

Comment: sorry if this is too direct: This error is a consequence of not understanding the difference between types and instances. I strongly suggest you to [grab a book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) and review the basics, because this misunderstanding has many symptoms (mostly errors that can be avoided easily)

Comment: Chances are you don't want to use unions in the first place.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because you are just defining a struct in your `control_pkt_u` union and it is just a declaration, it is not initialised when you create an object from it. You need to declare it as a member like this and reach your member `pkt_parts_`.

```
union control_pkt_u {
    struct pkt_parts_t {
        uint8_t header[3];                                // Control packet header
        uint8_t payload[NO_PYLD_BYTES_IN_CONTROL_PACKET]; // Control packet payload
    } pkt_parts_;
    uint8_t pkt_array[NO_BYTES_IN_PACKET];
};

pkt.pkt_parts_.header[0] = APP_MSG_DEB;
```

Comment: Isn't `pkt.pkt_parts_t_.header[0] = APP_MSG_DEB;` a typo?

Answer (score 2):

You can change the struct definiation to this by using **Anonymous structure**:

```
struct {
    uint8_t header[3];                                // Control packet header
    uint8_t payload[NO_PYLD_BYTES_IN_CONTROL_PACKET]; // Control packet payload
} pkt_parts_t;
```

Then you don't need to change other code.